# JavaScript - Inherit properties between multiple instances

Tags: javascript, object, properties, instance

I have some difficulties to understand the way to share between multiple instances properties/methods.

I know that's possible to inherit properties by creating a new object `Object.create()` of an instance. But it creates a new object which can't be shared across several (child) instances.

My aim is to create a Parent function which holds properties and helper methods. And this properties/methods should be shared across children functions. When a child (or parent) method modifies a property, it should be accessible and reflected in all instances (parent/children).

How can achieve a such behaviour?

Here an example of classical inheritance (which is not what I want) but illustrate the principle I want to achieve:

```
// File 1 - Parent
var Parent = function() {
    this.var1 = 'var1';
    this.var2 = 'var2';
};

Parent.prototype.setVar = function( name, arg ) {
    this[name] = arg
};

Parent.prototype.getVar = function( name ) {
    return this[name];
};

// File 2 - Child 1
var Child1 = function() {
    Parent.call( this );
};

Child1.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
Child1.prototype.constructor = Child1;

Child1.prototype.print = function() {
    this.setVar( 'var1', 'test var 1' );
    this.setVar( 'var2', 'test var 2' );
    console.log( this.var1, this.var2 )
};

// File 3 - Child 2
var Child2 = function() {
    Parent.call( this );
};

Child2.prototype = Object.create( Parent.prototype );
Child2.prototype.constructor = Child2;

Child2.prototype.print = function() {
    console.log(this.var1, this.var2)
};

var Child1 = new Child1();
var Child2 = new Child2();
Child1.print(); // test var 1 test var 2
Child2.print(); // var1 var2

/*** => How to share/inherit the variables from Parent in all children (Child1, Child2, etc...)
Child1.print(); // test var 1 test var 2
Child2.print(); // test var 1 test var 2
***/
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/guL2ahpq/

Maybe I'm very far of the concept I'm looking for.
I hope someone can explain in an easy way how to achieve what I'm looking for. I guess I've got some lack of knowledge in OOP...

Comment: While JS can read a 'shared property' (from the prototype chain) it will always create a local property when writing.

Comment: Yes, I know. But how to implement code in order to share across all instances the same properties which can be updated anywhere? Is there a way to achieve this in OOP?

Comment: You can't update a shared property. That's how JS works.

Comment: That's not true, you can create an object outside all instances and inject it in all instances in order to achieve that. But I'm looking for the right implementation/OOP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set those variables on the prototype object of `Parent` that all the instances inherit:

```
function Parent() {}
Parent.prototype.var1 = 'var1';
Parent.prototype.var2 = 'var2';
Parent.prototype.setVar = function(name, arg) {
    Parent.prototype[name] = arg
};
```

Of course this is a rarely used pattern and will lead to a lot of confusion. Do not put mutable shared properties on instances. You could achieve the same by simply using a global variable, or static properties of `Parent`.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an example with static properties?

Comment: Just store them on `Parent` or `mySingleton` or whatever instead of `Parent.prototype`. And don't access them through `this` in the `print` methods, but explicitly on that object.

Answer (score -1):

Check the example here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance

Also there's a chapter about Object Oriented JS
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS